# Is there a way to hasManyThrough two joined pivot tables in Laravel query builder?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, query-builder, has-many-through

I truly hope some of you smart guys can help me with a problem above my pay grade ;)

*How could I find all users connected to a certain Subpart, given the following situation?*

Anyone have any insights? Or even whether or not this is actually a solid implementation of the problem at hand?

## Given:

- A Project has Elements. n:m
- An Element has Subparts. n:m
- Users can be assigned to Projects (I call this an Assignment). m:m
- Users may also potentially be assigned to one or more Subparts of an Element on the Project they are assigned to (AssignmentSubpart). m:m
- Assignment and AssignmentSubpart pivots have extra attributes and functions on them so they are made into a model extending Pivot.

I've opted for joining the two pivot tables because a User can be assigned to a Project without being assigned to a Subpart *yet*. Every user will be assigned to one or more subparts eventually, but I need "general" information like constraints and expenses (saved on the Assignment model) to be present with every Subpart-Talent connection.

## My Tables (simplified)

**projects:** id

**elements:** id, project_id

**subparts:** id, element_id

**users:** id

**assignment:** id, project_id, user_id, archived, constraints, expenses

**assignments_subparts:** id, assignment_id, subpart_id, description

## Things I've tried

Normally I would use a simpler hasManyThrough from Subpart to Talent, but since I'm actually joining two pivot tables (assignments and assignemnts_subparts) things are not working out like it should. I can't seem to hasManyThrough beyond the Assignment model.

I've taken a look at Steidenmeir's has-many-deep package, but I haven't the faintest clue how to set up the correct array of ID's and foreign keys...

## My models

```php
class Project extends Model
{
    public function elements()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Element::class);
    }

    public function subparts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Subpart::class, Element::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'assignments')->using(Assignment::class)->as('assigns')->withPivot(['id', 'archived']);
    }
}


class Assignment extends Pivot
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Users::class);
    }

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }

    public function subparts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subpart::class, 'assignments_subparts', 'assignment_id', 'subpart_id')->using(AssignmentSubpart::class)->as('assignsubpart');
    }
}


class AssignmentSubpart extends Pivot
{
    //
}


class Subpart extends Model
{
    public function element()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Element::class, 'element_id');
    }

    public function assignments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Assignment::class, 'assignments_subparts', 'subpart_id', 'assignment_id')->using(AssignmentSubpart::class)->as('assignsubpart');
    }

    // 
    // And here is the part I need working:
    //

    public function users()
    {
        return null; 
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't see any strong reason coming from you (just because it has an extra attribute, it doesnt mean they can't be a pivot) to setup the relation between assignment and subpart, eventhough it has an extra attribute, it would be better you set it as pivot table with only assignment_id , subpart_id, description
then you can use simple has many through via assignment

you can check in here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many on retrieving intermediate table columns

Comment: Thanks Giffari, Please let me clarify: The example models are quite heavily simplified. There are not only attributes but also some more complex functions (as stated previously) present on the pivots. I'm working on some event listeners which have to respond to changes on the pivots as well, and then a Model makes much more sense.
In your case though: suppose the pivots are just pivots, how would I set up my Subpart model relation to find the Subpart -> AssignmentSubpart -> Assignment -> User(s)? hasManyThrough doesn't seem to work for two joining pivots in between models as far as I can see.

Comment: I'm the author of the `eloquent-has-many-deep` package. Can you provide a raw SQL query that returns the expected result?